# GUI for copying (Ctrl+C) selected email addresses

Tags: gui-design

In a app view I have a list of persons. Each person has an email address, among other information. In front of each person there is a checkbox. The users can check these checkboxes to perform operations on several persons at the same time. One of these operations are: *"Copy (Ctrl+C) all email addresses from selected users"*. The users can then paste this string of email addresses into another email client, for example outlook.

I need a icon for this operation, or some other UI element to explain for the users what's expected and happening.

Comment: (ctrl+C) is throwing me off. Are you notifying the user that ctrl+c will copy emails? looking for an icon (or button) that will automatically copy e-mails? or both?

Comment: I am looking for a button, that will explain to the user that it will "collect" all selected users email adresses.... 

So he can paste them into another program. To manually copy all email adresses one by on is to messy... better to select with checkboxes and then press the "collect email adresses button" =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

If you have multiple actions you can perform on checked e-mails, you can select it from a dropdown. If not, you can just make a button that says "Copy E-mails" "Copy Selected" "Copy to Clipboard" etc... Then flash a notification that they have been copied successfully.

[image]

Comment: That's sort of the gmail model. I can't think of anything better right now, even though I'm not a great fan. I think it tends to be a bit ambiguent what elements the dropdown will perform actions on. You did state "copy selected" though, which does help.